# Is there no way to change background color DYNAMICALLY in PyQt5?

Tags: python, dynamic, colors, background, pyqt5

I'm writing an application in Python, using PyQt5.
I really want to change the background of QLable, QTextEdit, or anything that I can show some colors DYNAMICALLY.

I already saw a lot of examples of changing the background color of something, but all of them seems that I need to make some "palette" thing in advance.

What I want to do is that change background color based on the user's keyboard input which indicates a color like this: **#fffff** or **(255, 255, 255)**.
So is there really no way to implement this??

It doesn't matter the type of object I should use. It's just enough to be a rectangle shape.

Comment: You don't have a lot of choices, you either use QPalette, or [`setStyleSheet()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) (see [Qt Style Sheets Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)). If you want to do it "dynamically" you should be more specific about what do you mean by it, and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far, even if it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I really tried to add an actual code as an example, but I couldn't cos this is my first time to use PyQt5... and I wasn't able to find anything related to what I want.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, what I'm expecting is like this:

Comment: 1. User gives some input about color in the format like "#ffffff" or "(255, 255, 255)". It's hex or RGB

Comment: 2. and Then my program changes the background color into the given input color. That's all. Why is this so difficult in PyQt5??

Comment: It's not *difficult* per se. It *is* difficult if you don't know PyQt enough yet, like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example how to change the background colour dynamically by using `setStyleSheet`. The background color of the widget changes to whatever color is entered on the input line. Colors can be entered as a named html color (red, blue, yellow, etc.) or as a hex code in the form #rrggbb.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setPlaceholderText('Enter a color')
        self.line_edit.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit {background-color:white}')
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)

        self.line_edit.editingFinished.connect(self.change_background)

    def change_background(self):
        col = self.line_edit.text()
        self.setStyleSheet(f'QWidget {{background-color: {col};}}')
        self.line_edit.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.resize(400,300)
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with this.